# How to access gmail data in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am building an iphone application in which I have email client using IMAP. I want to use gmail data API but I can not find out how. Could you tell me how to solve this problem. is there any way to access gmail data?

```
Infrastructure:
Iphone device: Iphone 4.
Operating system:MAC OS 10.6.8,  iOS X
```

Comment: what kind of data do you want to fetch ?

Comment: In my application, I could fetch mail list. Moreover, when I Open a message on my app, on the server mark a message as read automatically. When I Delete a message in inbox on my app, on the server side Remove the message from inbox automatically. Generally I want my app act as IMAP mail client.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do so:

First:
As you have used IMAP, you can fetch the data from gmail using the keywords.

Have a look at [imap custom keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632102/imap-custom-keywords) for information on using keywords.

Second:
Have a look at the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/code.html) for fetching data using OAuth which should work with your client without any problems.

Comment: I have already fetched the data from gmail successfully, but how can I update gmail data, such as when i delete message, move message to orther folder on my app, it is synchronized automatically on the server side

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an IMAP client, IMAP seems like the right way to go. Take a look at Google's [Gmail documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/docs/) to learn about authenticating with OAuth so that you can access the server.